# How can I parse attachment part, which type is multipart/related in SAAJ (SOAP Messages with Attachments)?

Tags: java, soap, saaj, mm7

I receive an SAAJ message with [SOAP with Attachments API for Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhf.html), that contain multipart/related attachment. One part of this attachment is multipart/related too. That is I have [AttachmentPart](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/AttachmentPart.html) with multipart/related content. Is there a standard way to parse it?

In particular, I need to parse MMS(MM7)-message

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

All I need is cast AttachmentPart.getContent()'s result to MimeMultipart

```
MimeMultipart mp = (MimeMultipart) attachment.getContent();
for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
    Part bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
    if (bp.isMimeType("text/*")) {
        String text = (String)bp.getContent();
        //process text
    } else if (bp.isMimeType("image/*")) {
        InputStream is = bp.getInputStream();
        //process image 
    }
}
```